# Can you explain the meaning of the phrase "Worry plays no part in that"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> So far, you have been able to handle every challenge life has presented to you, both in expected and unexpected situations, and I can promise you that you will be able to handle whatever happens today and tomorrow, too. This is what true confidence is all about. It is not about feeling certain, it is about dealing with uncertainty. **Worry plays no part in that**

What does the phrase "Worry plays no part in that" mean in the paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

["To play a part in something"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/have-play-a-part-in-something) means to be involved in or contribute to it.  The negation of this would be "to play no part in something" (or "to not play a part in something").  So, we can rephrase "worry plays no part in that" as

> Worry does not contribute to that.

["Worry"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/worry_2) here is being used as a noun, meaning "the state of worrying."

Finally, I think *that*, in this sentence, is referring to "dealing with uncertainty" from the previous sentence.

Another way to say this, which I think gets across the author's point, is

> Worrying does not help you deal with uncertainty.

(As opposed to confidence, which the author claims *can* help you deal with uncertainty).

Comment: "This" = "what true confidence is all about" = "dealing with uncertainty" = "that". They all refer to the same thing, but I suppose your choice is the "best" one because there's a sort of unwritten rule whereby we choose the *nearest* credible antecedent noun (the first one encountered working *backward* from the ambiguous reference).